# Derby "A truncation error was encountered trying to shrink CLOB '<stream-value>' to length 255"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, derby

I have a column definition in my JPA entity.

```
@Lob
String message;
```

I have following error when I try to persist my entity with some message.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Java exception: 'A truncation error was encountered trying to shrink CLOB '' to length 255.: org.apache.derby.iapi.services.io.DerbyIOException'.
>
> Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.services.io.DerbyIOException: A truncation error was encountered trying to shrink CLOB '' to length 255.

I'm using Hibernate 4.2.15.Final with Apache Derby 10.10.2 and schema generation during testing. It looks like the length of the column is limited to 255. How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Derby dialect in Hibernate generates column definition with limited legth:

```
message clob(255)
```

You may want to override this behaviour and set your own length or leave default length. You may use

```
@Column(columnDefinition="clob")
@Lob
String message;
```

Remember that in derby

> A CLOB without a specified length is defaulted to two gigabytes (2,147,483,647)

Comment: Putting it like that makes it sound like each CLOB takes up 2GB. That is not the case. The limit is 2GB, but you can store small clobs without wasting space. So the 255 default limit in Hibernate seems strange...

Comment: With the above as @Column(columnDefinition="clob",length=6000) still the same message?

Answer (score 0):

This is regarded as a bug in Hibernate https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7264 and https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1501 but it's not going to be fixed as it seems.

> Hibernate does not take into account the length/scale/precision nor
>   the dialect when determining the Hibernate Type to use for a property
>   which omitted specifying one. What it does is to basically choose a
>   default based solely on the Java type

The base class of all Derby Dialects (DB2Dialect) does this:

```
registerColumnType( Types.CLOB, "clob($l)" );
```

You can hook declare a Hibernate DialectResolver which does something like:

```
private class DerbyTenSevenDialectWithClob extends DerbyTenSevenDialect {
    public DerbyTenSevenDialectWithClob() {
        super();
        registerColumnType( Types.CLOB, "clob" );
    }
}
```

I just verified that using Hibernate 5.3.7 and Derby 10.12.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is my solution for **hibernate-core-4.2.7** and **Derby**:

If you create a string columns they will become VARCHAR(255)

```
@Column()
    private String userName;
```

BUT you can **increase the length**, for example to 1000 characters by doing :

```
@Column(length = 1000)
   private String description;
```

PS: I had to drop/delete my old table to force create a new with the correct size, also have a look inside the *@Column* interface there is some useful stuff there like unique, ullable, updatable